# kubernetes installation on RHEL8 Fatal:docker.service not found

Tags: docker, kubernetes, installation, podman

I am trying to install kubernetes on aws instance(RHEL8) but while running kubeadm init it gives me back docker.service not found. I did some digging and I found that

> The docker package is not shipped or supported by Red Hat for Red Hat
>    Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 8. The docker container engine is replaced by a suite of tools in the Container Tools module.

now my question is how to install docker for kubernetes cluster? and If docker is not supported then what are the other options to launch kubernetes on RHEL8.
How can we do the installation of kubernetes on RHEL8 with that other options?
A detailed answer would be helpful.
Thank You.

Comment: Note that while you can install Kubernetes with the methods below, there are still some incompatibilities, most severely RHEL8 not supporting the legacy iptables mode, which will cause problems when exposing services and other network configuration. Best stick to RHEL7 / some other distro for now or try Openshift. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#ensure-iptables-tooling-does-not-use-the-nftables-backend

Answer (score 1):

Use CRI-O as the container runtime instead of Docker. [OpenShift uses CRI-O](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/red-hat-openshift-container-platform-4-now-defaults-cri-o-underlying-container-engine) on RHEL8 so it is well supported ([here's why](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/why-red-hat-investing-cri-o-and-podman)).

[CRI-O includes some docco for kubeadm](https://github.com/cri-o/cri-o/blob/master/tutorials/kubeadm.md).

Answer (score 1):

Quoting a statement from [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3696691) doc.

> The docker package is not shipped or supported by Red Hat for Red Hat
>   Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 8. The docker container engine is replaced by
>   a suite of tools in the Container Tools module.

You need to use [CRI-O](https://cri-o.io/) as container runtime instead of docker, [this](https://github.com/cri-o/cri-o/blob/master/tutorials/kubeadm.md) doc will help.

OR

Try [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-docker-in-rhel-8) hack to install docker-ce on rhel-8.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install docker manually using yum package manager. Then you should be able to initialize kubeadm